# SQL SERVER 2005 Automatic Schedule Backup Working not Properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am having a web server with install of WINDOWS 2003 Server and SQL SERVER 2005 Currently and i try to do a job schedule with the use of some control that i created. every thing is working properly but when it starts the job (in job i have written T-SQL Command for Backup Database) it will gives following error. i already check that i got the root directory path. and i have all the permission on that folder and i am as a DBOWNER of my database. but still i got error if any one or any person having idea regarding my error please help me immideately. please

****I am here gives path that is root directory of my Application ok****
MY ERROR :

Cannot open backup device 'C:\Inetpub\httpdocs\Full_BackUp_at21032009_092140AM.bak'. Device error or device off-line. See the SQL Server error log for more details. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

So, Please Help me if you having any ideas regarding why this error cause then if u wish to send solution directly me on this mail id : divyeshnh@gmail.com

Thank you

Sorry But I have whole rights that i wants at the root directory because i save my image files into this directory . so, you can understand that i have the rights.

Thank you for reply

i also do another thing :

i read yr answer very carefully & study all the things that u previously say. after that i try another thing that is i place that code on one button click event and fortunately i got success. so, i ask you when i try to do with schedule it will raised me an error while i click on button & take backup it will work fine. so, please give me answer about this.

Thank you for your reply

Thanks

Comment: What account does the SQL Server Agent service use?

Comment: What image files do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Do the accounts used by SQL Server and Agent services have permissions to access the *C:\Inetpub\httpdocs* folder?

Answer (score 0):

Are all the folders you your path already created? I think they have to already exist or you'll get an error.